# Insert .sql file into your MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP. In this I made a database via PhpMyadmin.

How can I upload a SQL file to the database?

Comment: You could have found your answer in Google faster then typing your question here

Answer (score 10):

Follow the setps to upload your sql file to database.

1. Run this link from your browser `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`.
2. Select `Database` which you want to upload the `SQL` file. (If no DB , create new database).
3. Click on Import option from top menu section and upload you files.

Please check the screenshots for your reference.

[image]
[image]
Try It... This will helps you....

Answer (score 6):

In your mysql console you have to type this command :

```
mysql> use YourDataBaseName
mysql> source YourFile.sql
```

or in your console type :

```
mysql -u root -p [YourPassword] [YourDataBaseName < YourFile.sql
```

For more information you can visit: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/

Answer (score 1):

In phpmyadmin choose import in the top menu and open your sql file from that page

Answer (score 0):

[How to import a SQL file into your database using phpMyAdmin](http://www.dewahost.com/tutorials/cpanelx/importsqlfile.html)